# File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'Check' is undefined

Tags: python, user-interface, flask, pyautogui

i want create data entry form using python GUI,if i run in terminal i got error massage like this :

```
File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'Check' is undefined
```

but if i run on debug mode i got message error like this:

```
Exception has occurred: UndefinedError 'Check' is undefined
```

**Here my code:**

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


dokumen_path = Path(__file__).parent / "word_template.docx"
doc = DocxTemplate(dokumen_path)

def tanggal_waktu():
    hari = datetime.datetime.today()
    return hari

layout = [
    [sg.Text("GUEST NAME"), sg.Input(key="NAMA", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("CHECK-IN"), sg.Input(key="Check-in", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("CHECK-OUT"), sg.Input(key="Check-out", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("ROOM NO"), sg.Input(key="KAMAR",do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("TYPE"), sg.Input(key="TIPE",do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("PERSON"), sg.Input(key="ORANG", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("ROOM CHARGE"), sg.Input(key="RC",do_not_clear=False),],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()],
]

window = sg.Window("Invoice Palm Garden Guest House", layout, element_justification="right")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
        break
    if event == "Submit":
        print(values)
        values["D/T"] = tanggal_waktu()
        values["TOTAL"] = int(values["RC"])
        doc.render(values)
        output_path = Path(__file__).parent / f"{values['NAMA']}-Invoice.docx"
        doc.save(output_path)
        sg.popup("File Saved")
    else:
        pass


window.close()
```

**Here my word template**

[word template picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBEs7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this error it is because the jinja library is not able to render the variables defined in word_template.docx template. For example you need to change the variable such as `{{D/T}}` to `{{ d_t }}` or something meaningful name such as `{{ time }}`. You to read documentation of jinja2 variables definition `https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/` you can also define variables in this format

```
{{ foo.bar }}
{{ foo['bar']}}
```

If you pass foo dictionary with key `bar` while rendering value of bar will be saved.

Modified code:
invoice_gui.py

```
"""
invoice_gui.py
"""
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
import argparse


def tanggal_waktu():
    hari = datetime.datetime.today()
    return hari

layout = [
    [sg.Text("GUEST NAME"), sg.Input(key="name", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("CHECK-IN"), sg.Input(key="check_in", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("CHECK-OUT"), sg.Input(key="check_out", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("ROOM NO"), sg.Input(key="room",do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("TYPE"), sg.Input(key="type",do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("PERSON"), sg.Input(key="person", do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.Text("ROOM CHARGE"), sg.Input(key="rc",do_not_clear=False),],
    [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Exit()],
]

def main(args):
    template_name = args.name
    print('template_name: %s' % (template_name))
    dokumen_path = Path(__file__).parent / "{}".format(template_name)
    doc = DocxTemplate(dokumen_path)
    window = sg.Window("Invoice Palm Garden Guest House", layout, element_justification="right")
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Exit":
            break
        if event == "Submit":
            print(values)
            values["time"] = tanggal_waktu()
            values["total"] = int(values["rc"])
            doc.render(values)
            output_path = Path(__file__).parent / f"{values['name']}-Invoice.docx"
            doc.save(output_path)
            sg.popup("File Saved")
        else:
            pass
    window.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python GUI script for invoice generator')
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--name',
                        default='word_template.docx', help='Specify the file name of word_template. Default is `word_template.docx`')
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

How to run the code

```
python invoice_gui.py -n word_template.docx
```

Modified template with variables.
[image]